# Strange validation error for form

Tags: php, forms, validation

The error i got was:

> Notice: Undefined index: visible in C:\xampp\htdocs\introducingphp\includes\validation_function.php on line 22

It should not happen since i already instantiated all the variables including visible

Validation_function.php

```
<?php

$errors = array();

function fieldname_as_text($fieldname) {
    $fieldname = str_replace("_", " ", $fieldname);
    $fieldname = ucfirst($fieldname);
    return $fieldname;
}

// * presence
// use trim() so empty spaces don't count
// use === to avoid false positives
// empty() would consider "0" to be empty
function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && $value !== "";
}

function validate_presences($required_fields) {
    global $errors;
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
        if (!has_presence($value)) {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";   
  }
 }
}

// * string length
// max length
function has_max_length($value, $max) {
    return strlen($value) <= $max;
}

function validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths) {
    global $errors;
    // Expects an assoc. array
    foreach($fields_with_max_lengths as $field => $max) {
        $value = trim($_POST[$field]);
      if (!has_max_length($value, $max)) {
        $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " is too long";
      }
    }
}

// * inclusion in a set
function has_inclusion_in($value, $set) {
    return in_array($value, $set);
}

?>
```

new_page.php (the page that has the one-page submit form that does validation)

```
<?php require_once("includes/session.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/db_connection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/validation_function.php"); ?>

<?php find_selected_page(); ?>

<?php
// Can't add a new page unless there is a subject as a parent
if (!$current_subject) {
    // subject ID was missing or invalid or
    //subject couldn't be found in database
    redirect_to("manage_content.php");
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Process the form

//validations
    $required_fields = array("menu_name", "position", "visible",
"content");
validate_presences($required_fields);

$fields_with_max_lengths = array("menu_name" => 60);
validate_max_lengths($fields_with_max_lengths);

    if (empty($errors)) {
      // perform Create

    //add the subject_id
    $subject_id = $current_subject["id"];
    $menu_name = mysql_prep($_POST["menu_name"]);
    $position = (int) $_POST["position"];
    $visible = (int) $_POST["visible"];
    //escape content
    $content = mysql_prep($_POST["content"]);

    // 2. Perform database query
    $query .= "INSERT INTO pages (";
    $query .= " subject_id, menu_name, position, visible,
    content";
    $query .= ") VALUES (";
    $query .= " {$subject_id}, '{$menu_name}', {$position},
    {$visible}, '{$content}'";
    $query .= ")";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);


    if ($result ) {
        // Success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Page Created.";

        redirect_to("manage_content.php?subject=" .
        urlencode($current_subject["id"]));
    }else {
        // Failure
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Page creation failed.";
    }   
  }
} else {
     // This is probably a GET request

} // End: If(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
<?php $layout_context = "admin"; ?>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="main">
<div id="navigation">
<?php echo navigation($current_subject, $current_page); ?>
</div>
<div id="page">
<?php echo message(); ?>
<?php echo form_errors($errors); ?>

<h2>Create Page</h2>
<form action="new_page.php?subject=<?php echo
urlencode($current_subject["id"]); ?>" method="post">
<p>Menu name:
<input type="text" name="menu_name" value="" />
</p>
<p>Position:
<select name="position">
<?php
$page_set =
find_all_pages_for_subject($current_subject["id"], false);
$page_count = mysqli_num_rows($page_set);
for($count=1; $count <= ($page_count + 1); $count++) {
   echo "<option value=\"{$count}\">{$count}</option>";   
}
?>
</select>
</p>
<p>Visible
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="0" /> NO
&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="visible" value="1" /> Yes
</p>
<p>Content:<br />
<textarea name="content" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Page" />
</form>
<br />
<a href="manage_content.php?subject=<?php echo
urlencode($current_subject["id"]); ?>">Cancel</a>
</div>
</div>

<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a typo on the input HTML field. You can use:

```
if (isset($_POST[$field])) {
```

on `validate_presences()` function to be sure that the value exists.

Comment: I followed the earlier suggestion of trimming at has_presence and it ended up not recognizing all the values. My visible is a tinyint actually and has a value of 0 for no and 1 for yes. Is that what that is affecting it ?

Comment: Echo the `$field` and `$_POST[$field]` variables in the `validate_presences()` function. It will give you a hint.

Comment: menu_name
Notice: Undefined index: visible in C:\xampp\htdocs\introducingphp\includes\validation_function.php on line 22
visiblecontent 

seems like it is printing out visible and content. although they are sort of stuck together.

Comment: And, have you marked one of the radio buttons? You also can try to do `var_dump($_POST)` before the error line to check out the array. This sure helps you to see what are you receiving from the form.

Comment: Yep, after marking one of the radio buttons it works now. Thank you very much

Comment: Perfect! Please, accept the answer if it has solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to do `trim($_POST[$field]);` you assume, the field exists in the `$_POST` array - for `visible` it does not in this case. You could move the `trim` to `has_presence()`

```
function has_presence($value) {
    return isset($value) && trim($value) !== "";
}

function validate_presences($required_fields) {
    global $errors;
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {
        if (!has_presence($value)) {
            $errors[$field] = fieldname_as_text($field) . " can't be blank";   
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you will only have the `trim` if the variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, marking the radio check button makes it work now. Thanks for all your inputs guys. It has helped me a great deal.